# django-cms and jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, django-cms

I've got a django site running quite happily with django-cms but now I want to include some of my own fancy javascript using jQuery. I'm rather new to django, so my problems might stem from this.

Django-cms uses jQuery itself, and so if I add jquery to the header - things break rathter unsurprisingly. How do I add my own jQuery without affecting django-cms?

At the moment my javascript files are stored in the media root which I've defined in the projects settings.py and, as mentioned, I reference them in the header.

As I read this, it seems a silly question, but I'm still perplexed.

EDIT::Some Code

I have a media root defined:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
```

and in my base template the header includes

```
<script src="/media/javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/javascript/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Javascript in application.js works, but it when the django-cms stuff is up it breaks. For example, trying to add a plugin to a placeholder results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'type' of object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    } is not a function
```

I assumed this was because the two jQuerys were conflicting with each other

::ANOTHER EDIT::
I should probably add that I'm using django to host the static files only because this is still in development...

Comment: Need clarification: Are you looking to use a different version of the jQuery library than what comes with Django-CMS, or do you just want to include your own custom scripts written in jQuery?

Comment: I don't mind using the bundled jQuery - but as far as I can see, it's only loaded when the django-cms admin bar etc exists. I do need to include some extra jquery ui elements and at least one plugin though.

Comment: Django shouldn't conflict with your jquery. Have you tried creating a static page and adding the jquery code to test? If you want to paste the code that is giving you problems here you will probably get a more specific reply.

Comment: Does anything in this thread help? http://old.nabble.com/jQuery-not-working---please-help-td20584563s27240.html

Comment: The javascript I write in application.js, for example if I had alert("It Works!!") that would run happily as would something more jQuery specific. But it breaks the django-cms stuff - I should have been more specific about what was actually breaking.

Comment: If I don't include my own jQuery or application.js then django-cms works... ideally I want everything working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution: keep your JQuery library in the header and place all other your JS at the boottom of the page, right before `</body>`. In this case in admin mode, your jQuery lib will be overrided by admin's copy, and then all of your code will be added back to it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, linking the django-cms's bundled jQuery does fix everything...

Alas, it uses version 1.3.2 but I think I'll deal with that rather than try and upgrade django-cms for now.